# manually running livereload in grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I've had to overwrite one of my watch event in grunt watch

```
grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath, target) ->
# does something ...
```

how can I manually trigger livereload at the end?

```
grunt.task.run('livereload'....)?
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this problem by setting the livereload on only one file which I write at the end of my process.

Here is an example:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->

  grunt.initConfig
    watch:
      reload:
        options:
          livereload: true
        files: "refresh.txt"
      css:
        files: ["**/*.css"]
      js:
        files: ["**/*.js]
    # ... and all your tasks

  grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath, target) ->
    # does something ...
    if target isnt 'reload'
      data = "#{grunt.template.today("isoDateTime")}\n"
      require('fs').appendFileSync "refresh.txt", data
```